# Can you use filters (CPL/UV/ND8) made for digital cameras with a film camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters, digital-vs-film

Just got this "Digital Filter Kit 2" from Hoya but planned on using it with a 35mm film camera. Does anyone have any experience with using "digital filters" with film cameras ? Does it work the same ? I'm asking because I read later that digital camera sensors are more sensitive than film and for example I find my polarizing filter very dark. It's like a sunglasses for my camera. Almost like the ND8 one from the kit. Hadn't got the chance to develop film shot with the filters on yet so if anyone can enlighten me before I burn a few rolls that would be awesome !

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

These will be fine. Digital sensors are more reflective than film, so *some* filters marketed for digital have coatings designed to minimize this reflection — same as [is there a real difference between "digital" and "film" lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53787/is-there-a-real-difference-between-digital-and-film-lenses). In other cases, it's just marketing and there's no difference at all.

Digital cameras *can* be more sensitive than film, but at the same ISO setting they are equivalent (this is the point of ISO, after all).

Polarizing filters *do* reduce the amount of light transmitted (some more than others). This is true no matter what camera you are attaching it to. Perhaps, if you were using a digital camera with an electronic viewfinder, the camera was brightening the preview to compensate (which is the default on many cameras — and which of course the film camera can't do).

Comment: @MFJC The best way to say "thanks" is to vote up answers you find helpful, and to click the "accepted" one by the answer that most answers your question. (Although you may want to wait for that for a little bit; even better answers may come in.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same. If your film camera's exposure meter works through the lens (TTL) it will compensate automatically for the light loss. If not, you will have to compensate the exposure by using a longer shutter time or wider aperture. What kind of film camera is it?

Comment: Thanks for your help as well ! It's an old viewfinder, the Olympus 35RC, but it has the light meter next to the lens, so behind the filter if i'm not wrong. I have to check !

Comment: Yes, the meter is behind the filter on that one, so it will work automatically. Hard to use the polarizer though, as you won't see the effect in the viewfinder.