# How do Canon's EF 35mm ƒ/2 and EF 35mm ƒ/2 IS USM lenses differ?

Tags: lens, canon

What's the difference between the Canon EF 35mm f/2 lens that was available in 2008, and the EF 35mm f/2 IS USM lens now available, apart from the £200 extra price difference?

Comment: Don't you suspect IS and USM mean something?

Comment: @osullic To be fair to the OP, I edited the question title and body to refer to the correct lens model names. OP didn't include "IS" as originally written (although, I think they did include "USM").

Answer (score 2):

The lenses are two totally different designs for the Canon EOS EF mount that have the same focal length and maximum aperture. They share little else in common.

EF 35mm f/2:

[image: EF 35mm f/2 block diagram]

- Introduced in 1990 shortly after the introduction of the EOS system in 1987.
- 7 lens elements in 5 groups.
- 5 blade aperture diaphragm.
- 0.25 meter minimum focusing distance with 0.23X maximum magnification
- 67.4mm wide x 42.5mm long weighing 210 grams.
- Arc form micro-AF motor with no full-time manual focus. (Turning the MF ring while the lens is set to AF can damage the AF motor or gearing)
- Fewer internal lens surfaces have anti-reflective coatings.

EF 35mm f/2 IS USM:

[image: EF 35mm f/2 IS block diagram]

- Introduced in 2012, 22 years after the EF 35mm f/2.
- 10 lens elements in 8 groups including a glass mold aspherical lens that effectively corrects for various aberrations, including curvature of field, making possible higher image quality than its predecessor.
- 8 blade circular aperture diaphragm.
- 0.24mm MFD with a 0.24X MM.
- 77.9mm wide x 62.6mm long weighing 335 grams.
- Ring type *Ultrasonic Motor* AF with full-time manual focus.
- Multi coatings on most internal lens elements to reduce flare and ghosting.
- *Image Stabilization* rated at four stops.

The newer EF 35mm f/2 IS USM is a modern lens design created for [use with digital cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/53788/15871). The EF 35mm f/2 was a film era lens that, while a good value and performer for its time, shows its age a bit when [used with digital cameras and held up to the higher level of scrutiny](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/91459/15871) expected by most photographers today.

There's also the newer (2015) and more expensive [EF 35mm f/1.4 L II USM](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef452.html) that is a significant improvement over the legendary [EF 35mm f/1.4 L USM](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef346.html) introduced in 1998.